# Permanent authentication with Express and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, slack

I have an express server with a post route that I want to secure.

I am making a slackbot that should be the only thing that posts to the server.

Is there a way to set up permanent authentication between the two apps?

One crude solution I can think of is to pass a secret in the request object.

Comment: That's not really a crude solution, so much *how people do this*: you share a secret between bot and server. As long as the transport is secure (HTTPS) you know that a request with that secret is valid. If you only have one client, you could just generate one manually and set it in an env var at each end.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe :)